# Hello all..I want to replace a character with an empty string..but replace won't take a char and a string..how to do it

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class example {
public static void main(String args[])
{
String l="hello";
String q="";
if(l.charAt(0)=='h' && l.charAt(l.length()-1)=='o')
{
    q=l.replace(l.charAt(0),"");   //It won't take char and "" together
}
}

}
```

like here I cant't replace 'h' with an empty space.I get the error

```
The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, String)`
```

Comment: And you choose to ignore the error message?

Comment: This signature simply does not exist. There is no signature of this method wich takes a `char` and a `String`, it's either two of one or two of the other.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like you're trying to replace `'h'` with a space, it looks like you're trying to trim it out entirely.

Comment: `q = l.replace(Character.toString(l.charAt(0)), "")` or `q = l.replace("" + l.charAt(0), "")` or `q = l.replace(l.substring(0, 1),"")`

Comment: Although, given that `l.charAt(0) == 'h'`, `l.replace("h", "")` seems easiest.

Answer (score 0):

In the `replace()` call, change `l.charAt(0)` to `l.substring(0, 1)`. This will return the same value (the first `char` in `l`), but as a `String` instead of a `char`.

Alternatively, since you are trying to always strip off the first letter, you could do the following:

```
q = l.substring(1);
```